# Datatable.js make table from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Suppose I have a set of objects that each contain data I want to store into a data table.  Per the documentation, I would normally do something like:

```
var dataSet = [
    ['Trident', 'Internet Explorer 4.0', 'Win 95+', '4', 'X'],
    ['Trident', 'Internet Explorer 5.0', 'Win 95+', '5', 'C'],
    ['Trident', 'Internet Explorer 5.5', 'Win 95+', '5.5', 'A'],
    ['Gecko', 'Camino 1.0', 'OSX.2+', '1.8', 'A'],
    ['Gecko', 'Camino 1.5', 'OSX.3+', '1.8', 'A'],
    ['Gecko', 'Netscape 7.2', 'Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2', '1.7', 'A'],
    ['Gecko', 'Netscape Browser 8', 'Win 98SE+', '1.7', 'A'],
    ['Gecko', 'Netscape Navigator 9', 'Win 98+ / OSX.2+', '1.8', 'A'],
    ['Misc', 'PSP browser', 'PSP', '-', 'C'],
    ['Other browsers', 'All others', '-', '-', 'U']
];
```

But my data is presented as an array of objects. Can I iterate through them in a for loop and get each piece of data? For example, if I have  an object, obj, that contains a title and a some data, the following does not work:

```
var finalObj = "["
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    finalObj = finalObj + "['" + obj[i].title + "','" + obj[i].data + "']";
}
finalobj = finalObj + "]";
```

This results in my datatable only containing one letter per column. What is the proper way to create a string (or other object) that will be formatted like the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved using the [data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/data) option in the initialization object, passing in an array of data to be used (like all other DataTables handled data, this can be arrays or objects using the [columns.data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option)

See the example below for code and demonstration.

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  
  var obj = [
        {
            "title": "Tiger Nixon",
            "data": "System Architect"
        },
        {
            "title": "Garrett Winters",
            "data": "Accountant"
        },
        {
            "title": "Ashton Cox",
            "data": "Junior Technical Author"
        }
  ];
  
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "data": obj,
    "columns": [
       { "data": "title" },
       { "data": "data" }
    ]
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Data</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Data</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So here again it looks like the data is hard-coded. I'm looking for what to do if I have an object that holds, say Tiger Nixon's information. How do I convert it to this? Would I just use `"\"name\":"+obj[i].name` ?

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer , my `data` variable is an object, not a string that you're trying to generate. You just need to pass `obj` as `"data": obj` instead of `"data": data` in my example and define object properties in `columns.data` option.

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer, changed my example to match your structure.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the example about the [javascript sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

As you can see for yourself it uses the following code to create the table

```
 $('#example').dataTable( {
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Engine" },
            { "title": "Browser" },
            { "title": "Platform" },
            { "title": "Version", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Grade", "class": "center" }
        ]
    } );
```

Comment: Yes, this is the example I referenced in my question. :) But I don't see how I can use it to get that data from an object. It seems here I still have to know ahead of time what my data will be.

Comment: The json you are using doen't give you specific data. It's just data, and you have to know what they represent. now if you have an object witch the property describes the value, you could do the following to populate the table:

   $.each(your_object, function(index, value) {         
            $("#your_table").DataTable().row.add([value.property1, value.property2, ....,value.propertyN]).draw();
        }
    });